# setState function is not working even though i am using stateful widget...whats the reason?

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, contactpicker

I am trying to select contact from phone and showing it on the text field., but the text field is not showing the changed value even though the variable is changing in the log. I am using contact picker package.

Here is the variable declaration:

[image: Here is the variable declaration]

the code for the contact button is

[image: remaining code]

Comment: Please use text for your code.   You can use `Code Sample` button in editor.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
_contactPicker.selectContact().then(
    setState((){
       _contact = contact;
    });
);
```

Instead of

```
Contact contact = await _contactPicker.selectContact();
setState((){
    _contact = contact;
});
```

And I am not sure about your ReusableEditText. You might need a TextEditingController if you didn't use that.